# bash printing thread affinity parsing

Tags: bash, function

I have the following function:

```
affinity ()
{
     local tid TASKSET CORE;
     for tid in $(ps -efL | awk '/foo.*d/ {print $4}');
     do
         TASKSET=($( taskset -pc $tid | awk -F"[' ]" '{print $2,$NF}' ));
         CORE[${TASKSET[1]}]="${CORE["${TASKSET[1]}"]} ${TASKSET[0]}";
     done;
     for i in "${!CORE[@]}";
     do
         printf "Core %-2s:%2s\n" "$i" "${CORE[$i]}";
     done
}
```

It usually prints something like this:

```
$ affinity
Core 5 : 2545
Core 9 : 14621 14640
Core 10: 1056
Core 11: 1081
```

I've noticed that it works well until I encounter a server that has more than 1 CPUs returned by `taskset` per thread, which breaks this script/function:

```
$ taskset -pc 14471
pid 14471's current affinity list: 0-3
$ taskset -pc 14621
pid 14621's current affinity list: 4,5
$ affinity
-bash: CORE: bad array subscript
-bash: CORE[${TASKSET[1]}]: bad array subscript
```

How would you suggest I improve this script to work with such case?

More details:

```
$ taskset
taskset (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)
usage: taskset [options] [mask | cpu-list] [pid | cmd [args...]]
set or get the affinity of a process

  -p, --pid                  operate on existing given pid
  -c, --cpu-list             display and specify cpus in list format
  -h, --help                 display this help
  -V, --version              output version information

The default behavior is to run a new command:
  taskset 03 sshd -b 1024
You can retrieve the mask of an existing task:
  taskset -p 700
Or set it:
  taskset -p 03 700
List format uses a comma-separated list instead of a mask:
  taskset -pc 0,3,7-11 700
Ranges in list format can take a stride argument:
  e.g. 0-31:2 is equivalent to mask 0x55555555
```

As for the type of the linux, it is a custom dist:

```
$ uname -a
Linux MySrv 2.6.32-358.23.2.61.foo.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 18 06:59:23 CDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks

Solution:
After aggregating all of the great clues and answers below, this is what I've came upto:
This also handles the 0,1,4-6 output that the initial question missed.

```
affinity ()
{
    local ii tid CORE CORES_STR CORES_ARR;
    for tid in $(ps -Leo tid,command | awk '/[f]oo.*d/ {print $1}');
    do
        CORES_STR=($(taskset -pc $tid | awk '{gsub(/,/," ",$NF);print $NF}'));
        CORES_ARR=();
        for ii in ${CORES_STR[@]};
        do
            [[ $ii =~ - ]] && CORES_ARR+=($(eval echo {${ii/-/..}})) || CORES_ARR+=($ii);
        done;
        for ii in ${CORES_ARR[@]};
        do
            CORE[${ii}]="${CORE[${ii}]} $tid";
        done;
    done;
    for ii in "${!CORE[@]}";
    do
        printf "Core %-2d:%2s\n" "$ii" "${CORE[$ii]}";
    done
}
```

Comment: Please post the output of `taskset` on both kinds of servers.  Also post a `uname -a`.

Answer (score 2):

Include a range parser in your function to identify all the cores from a range. Here an example of getting all of the cores in an array for a range. Then loop over that to add the process to all the cores.

```
#!/bin/bash

range=0,3,7-11
cores=()
while read part; do
    if [[ $part =~ - ]]; then
        cores+=($(seq ${part/-/ }))
    else
        cores+=($part)
    fi
done < <( echo $range | tr ',' '\n' )

for core in ${cores[*]}; do
    echo $core
done
```

Taking a cue from @bishop, this can be somewhat simplified with the eval and bash expansion, e.g.:

```
range=0,3,7-11
cores=()
IFS=',' read -ra parts <<<$range
for part in "${parts[@]}"; do
    [[ $part =~ - ]] && cores+=($(eval echo {${part/-/..}})) || cores+=($part)
done
```

Comment: The edited part doesn't work for me. Using `read -ra parts <<<${range//,/ }` fixes it for me.

Comment: Hmmm... it works for me -- are you including the `IFS=','` on the same line as the read? In any case, either way should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tasklist -pc 2420 14370 17654
pid 2420's current affinity list: 0-1
pid 14370's current affinity list: 0,2-4
pid 17654's current affinity list: 2-5,9,11,13-15

$ affinity_for_tid 2420 14370 17654
Core 0 : 2420 14370
Core 1 : 2420
Core 2 : 17654 14370
Core 3 : 17654 14370
Core 4 : 17654 14370
Core 5 : 17654
Core 9 : 17654
Core 11: 17654
Core 13: 17654
Core 14: 17654
Core 15: 17654

function affinity_for_tid() {
    declare -A map

    # give me every line from tasklist
    while read -r line; do
        # break it up into an array
        # array[0] === the tid, as a number; array[1] === the stripe
        IFS=' '
        local array=( $(awk '{print strtonum($2) " " $6}' <<<"$line") )

        # convert the stripe of form like "0,2-4" to "{0,{2..4}}"
        # so that shell brace expansion can deal with it
        local parts=(), stripe=()
        IFS=',' read -ra parts <<<"${array[1]}"
        for part in "${parts[@]}"; do
            if [[ $part == *-* ]]; then
                stripe+=("{${part//-/..}}")
            else
                stripe+=("$part")
            fi
        done

        # expand
        local expansion=$(IFS=,; echo "${stripe[*]}")
        if [[ $expansion == *,* ]]; then
            expansion="{$expansion}"
        fi
        local expanded=$(eval echo "${expansion}")

        # put the expansion into the map
        for cpu in $expanded; do
            map[$cpu]="${map[$cpu]} ${array[0]}"
        done
    done < <(tasklist -pc "@")

    # output as desired
    for cpu in "${!map[@]}"; do
        printf 'Core %-2d:%s\n' "$cpu" "${map[$cpu]}"
    done | sort -t ' ' -k 2n
}
```

Centrally, this converts the striped output of `taskset` into a bash brace expansion.  So "0,2-4" becomes "{0,{2..4}}".  The rest is just glue to move the data around, which can probably be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to expand my code w/ a range parser. (before seeing +zerodiff's answer :))

```
affinity ()
{
    CORE=()
    for tid in $(ps -efL | awk '/[f]oo.*d/ {print $4}');
    do
        CPU=$(taskset -pc $tid | awk -F"[' ]" '{print $NF}' );
        if [[ $CPU =~ "-" ]]; then
            for ii in $(seq ${CPU/-/ });
            do
                CORE[${ii}]="${CORE[${ii}]} $tid";
            done;
        else
            if [[ $CPU =~ "," ]]; then
                for ii in ${CPU/,/ };
                do
                    CORE[${ii}]="${CORE[${ii}]} $tid";
                done;
            else
                CORE[${CPU}]="${CORE[${CPU}]} $tid";
            fi;
        fi;
    done;
    for i in "${!CORE[@]}";
    do
        printf "Core %-2s:%2s\n" "$i" "${CORE[$i]}";
    done
}
```

+zerodiff's code looks cleaner. I'll try to incorporate it tomorrow :)